# ui-grid hide grid menu item (not all only export button)

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am using angular ui-grid and using external button to export as a csv file.

The final grid menu is similar to as attached.

From this, i need to remove the export as buttons. But the columns should be there in the grid menu.

How can i achieve this?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are gridOptions to hide the exportbuttons.

```
exporterMenuCsv: false,
exporterMenuPdf: false,
```

I created a [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/0OQM2JwBQ7UtbDvllUXu?p=preview).

Comment: It is working perfectly in the plnkr. When i download and refer to a local json file, to just make in my computer alone i.e standalone version i.e without internet it says cross domain issue. Can someone help me on how to make it work in a local system or folder - i will place the html, json, css and javascript in the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all references to the 'ui-grid-exporter' directive on your grid. That would remove all export options you see under the Grid Menu for all file formats.